# How to reload a tableView i.e call the viewDidLoad method if a condition is met

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

The problem is this i need a way to basically erase all the entry data a user placed into my arrays if a condition is met. Im new to Objective-C and iOS programming, but i believed the solution might be in calling the viewDidLoad method, thus it would virtually refresh the applications with the values of the array reset to default. If there is any other logical way of doing this i would appreciate the help.

In short i need to refresh the arrays as they were when the application first launched and the user did not select anything.

This is the part where i need it to refresh.

```
 if ([gradeRecieved objectAtIndex:i]==nil) {


            break; // if this condition is met the program must  begin anew.
```

Edit* I need to recall the - (void)viewDidLoad method

here is more of the code.

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{
    double sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double gradeEarned=0;
    double creditHours = 3;

    while (i<8){

       // [credits removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
        if ([credits count ] ==0) {
            break; 
        }

            if ([credits objectAtIndex:i] == radioButtonA) {

           // [gradeRecieved replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:GradeA];
                [defArray addObject:GradeA];
                gradeEarned+=GradeA.intValue;
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            if ([credits objectAtIndex:i] == radioButtonB) {
           // [gradeRecieved replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:GradeB];
                [defArray addObject:GradeB];
              gradeEarned+=GradeB.intValue;
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            if ([credits objectAtIndex:i]== radioButtonC){
         // [gradeRecieved replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:GradeC];
                [defArray addObject:GradeC];
                gradeEarned+=GradeC.intValue;
                i++;
                continue;

            }
        if ([credits objectAtIndex: i] == defaulter) {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Custom button pressed" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You pressed the custom button C"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"great"otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        [self viewDidLoad];
            break;
        }
    }

    if ([defArray count]>0) {

                sum= ([defArray count])/(creditHours*gradeEarned);
        NSLog(@"%f",sum);}
```

this new code however results in the app freezing if the user clicks the button and then try's to redo some selections made

Comment: You might want to check out my idea below about embedding your array in a tableview.

Comment: i was hoping for a quicker way to reload the arrays to their original values instead of programmatically doing so. As of with the program if the user does not select  a button the array values are set to nil. I wanted to display a message using the AlertView and then allow the user to undue their mistake by re -selecting the required buttons.

Comment: `-objectAtIndex:` cannot return nil, if you are talking about a NSArray. Not sure what the question is.

Comment: ross early stages i set the values of my array to [NSNull null] as a defaulter so i understand That -objectAtIndex cannot return nil values i have received that error however,that is not what the question was about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call that code again, wrap that code into a method and call that method in `viewDidLoad` and wherever else you want. Here is some example code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  if ([gradeRecieved objectAtIndex:i]==nil) {


          [self refreshArray];
}

}

- (void)refreshArray {

   // refresh here


}
```

Then call `[self refreshArray]` wherever you need!

I see you are new! If this answer was correct you can up vote or tick!

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to reload array data, not tableview data, but your comment is interesting, as now I realize that the OP could possibly place his data in a tableview that is not visible, and use your function to reload his data.

Comment: You were the inspiration! +1 to you @Rohan

Comment: Iv tried the [tableView reloadData]; method call but  that just like qegal said just reloads the data in my tableView.. What i really need is to  recall this method... -(void)viewDidLoad

Comment: Did you first put your data into a tableview? The reloadData method won't do anything on an array.

Comment: I know i misunderstood your question

Comment: If you want to reload viewDidLoad why not just call it? [self viewDidLoad];

Comment: hey rohan i went with your idea of the [self viewDidLoad];  However when i run the program and click the add button it sometimes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error displays

Comment: Yes I supposed that would happen. You cannot call [super viewDidLoad]; if the view is all loaded up. So basically

Comment: what you can do is put that code in a seperate method, call that method from viewDidLoad and call that method whenever you want to.... answer updated

Comment: Hey rohan thanks for the advice i re wrapped the part of my code i needed to refresh and created a method to refresh the array thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The viewDidLoad method loads only once - when the view is first loaded. To reload data, the easiest way is to create another method and call that method everytime you need to load data.

Example,

```
-(void)loadingData{

//code to load the data

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
//this will call the loadingData method to load the data
[self loadingData];

}
```